# What's the real use of the management/commands directory in the Django Application?

Tags: python-3.x, django, command, django-apps, django-management-command

In the documentation, it is written that it can be used for writing custom Django-admin commands. But my question is why do we need to write custom Django admin commands?  The given example in the official documentation is a bit dry to me. I would be really grateful if someone give real-world examples from which I can connect its real-life use.

Django doc on management/commands:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mainly use it from Cron / Scheduled Tasks..

Some potential examples would be:

1. Sending out Reports/Emails
2. Running Scripts to Update+Sync some Values
3. Updating the Cache
4. Any large update to values- save it to a command to run on the Prod Env

   - I make it + test it locally, but then I don't want to Copy+Paste it in a SSH terminal cause it sometimes gets all sorts of messed up in the paste.

I also have a management command `dothing` that sets up the entire project.. runs migrations, collects static, imports db, creates test users, creates required folder structures, etc.

I also have a couple of commands that **I** use, that I haven't made into Views.. Little tools to help me validate and clean data, spits out a representation of it

Answer (score 1):

Django scheduled operations and report generation from cron is the obvious one.

Another I use is for loading data into the DB from csv files. It's easy in the management command environment to handle bad rows. I write the original csv row into an exceptions file (with a error-description column appended) and can then look at it and decide what to do about these rows. Sometimes, just a trivial edit and feed it through the management command again. It's possible to do the same via a view, but extra work for IMO no gain.